# useEffect and 'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps' linting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, use-effect

I included an empty array because this should only run once, however I'm getting the linting warning because I'm not including `ajaxCallsInProgress` as a dependency. The reason I don't is that it creates an infinite loop if I do. Is there a better way to handle this scenario that will eliminate the linting warning? This is pretty straight-forward and a valid scenario as far as I can tell.

```
useEffect(() => {
     const fetch = async () => {
         // update state to show pending
         setAjaxCallsInProgress(ajaxCallsInProgress + 1)

         try {
             const humans = await getHumans()

             setHumans(humans)
         } catch (error) {
             setError(error)
         } finally {
             setAjaxCallsInProgress(ajaxCallsInProgress - 1)
         }
     }

     fetch()
}, [])
```

Comment: Are you defining `setAjaxCallsInProgress` and `ajaxCallsInProgress` with `useState()`?

Comment: @norbitrial yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In-/decrementing the state doesn't require you to know the current state because `setState` has a [callback version](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate) that receives the current state as an argument and returns the next state:

```
const [ajaxCallsInProgress, setAjaxCallsInProgress] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
        // update state to show pending
        setAjaxCallsInProgress(current => current + 1)

        try {
            const humans = await getHumans()

            setHumans(humans)
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error)
        } finally {
            setAjaxCallsInProgress(current => current - 1)
       }
   }

    fetch()
}, [])
```

This will remove the dependency on `ajaxCallsInProgress` and is also a [best practice](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#how-do-i-update-state-with-values-that-depend-on-the-current-state) for updating state based on the current state:

> **How do I update state with values that depend on the current state?**
>
> Pass a function instead of an object to `setState` to ensure the call 
>   always uses the most updated version of state (see below).

You should generally use it when accessing the current state to update the state.

Comment: Ah, there it is. Thank you!